# Менять ли 127.0.0.1

Tags: php, html, php7

Всем привет , у меня такой вопрос , есть у меня сайт на котором все ссылки прописаны типа 127.0.0.1/ru/index.php , после загрузки на хостинг полагаю мне придется менять 127.0.0.1 на example.com ? 
И во всех ссылках сайта сменить локалхост на домен?

А если мне нужно протестировать много страниц именно с ссылками на локалхост , что делать тогда?

Comment: Надо использовать относительные ссылки

Comment: я использую , но например у меня на сайте 3 версии языка , и на каждом ссылка типа 127.0.0.1/ru/index.php 
каким образом я буду использовать относительные ссылки если они в разных папках располагаются?

Comment: ссылку `http://127.0.0.1/ru/index.php` пишите как `/ru/index.php`. Браузер сам допишет адрес хоста. А при переключении на другой язык сделаете соответственно `/en/index.php` или как вам нравится.

Comment: А в чрезвычайно редких случаях, когда все таки нуден адрес хоста (например при переходе с http страницы, на https) храните адрес в единственной переменной в настройках и берете от туда всегда, а не пишите явно везде в коде

Comment: Mike спасибо , вопрос , но если я сделаю внутри /ru/index.php ссылку на  /en/index.php , разве браузер не будет искать эту самую /en/index.php внутри папки ru??

Comment: первый "/" - смотреть от корня, webroot, куда смотрит сам домен